# Oracle 11G table exists but not usable

Tags: oracle11g

I'm running Oracle 11G. Assume I have table named TEST_TABLE. I can see it when run :

```
SQL> SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM ALL_TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME='TEST_TABLE';

TABLE_NAME
------------------------------
TEST_TABLE
```

But when I try to get table content I get an error:

```
SQL>  SELECT * FROM table (TEST_TABLE);
SELECT * FROM table (TEST_TABLE)
                  *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00904: "TEST_TABLE": invalid identifier
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated !

Comment: SELECT * FROM TEST_TABLE;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table (TEST_TABLE);
```

That is the syntax for using a table *function*. Quite [an advanced topic](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/pipelined-table-functions.php), not what you are looking for.

To access a table, simply do

```
SELECT * FROM TEST_TABLE;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Now everything fine !